# I'm trying to call a javascript function from the onClick event but as far as I know the function isn't being called.

Tags: php, javascript

```
<style type="text/css">@import url("cstyle.css");</style>
<style type="text/css">@import url("style.css");</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteComment(id)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","deleteComment.php?id="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    deleteComment(id);

});
</script>
<?php
include_once("pass.php");
include("common.php");

class ComA
{   
    static function reportComment()
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE Flag =1"); 
        $number=mysql_num_rows($query);
        // number of rows to show per page
        $rowsperpage = 15;
        // find out total pages
        $totalpages = ceil($number / $rowsperpage);
        // get the current page or set a default
        if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) 
        {
           // cast var as int
           $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
        } 
        else 
        {
           // default page num
           $currentpage = 1;
        } 
        //if current page is greater than total pages...
        if ($currentpage > $totalpages) 
        {
           // set current page to last page
           $currentpage = $totalpages;
        } 
        //if current page is less than first page...
        if ($currentpage < 1) 
        {
           // set current page to first page
           $currentpage = 1;
        }
        //the offset of the list, based on current page 
        $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;
        // get the info from the db 
        // while there are rows to be fetched...
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE Flag = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage"); 
        ?>
        <div id="count">
        <div id="title"><b>Edit Reported Comments</b></div>
        <?php
        if($number==1)
            echo $number . " COMMENT";
        else
            echo $number . " COMMENTS";
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        while ($content = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            ?>
            <div id="delete">
            <?php $javaid=$content['id']; ?>
                <a href="<?php $_GET['location'] ?>" onClick="deleteComment(<?php echo $javaid ?>)" ><img src="_" onmouseover="_" onmouseout="_"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="comment">
            <?php
            echo $content['username'] . " <br/> " ;
            ?>
            <div id="timestamp">
            <?php
            echo "Posted " . $content['date'];      
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            echo $content['comment'];
            ?>
            </div>
            <div class="greyRule"><hr /></div>
            <?php
        } // end while

        /******  build the pagination links ******/
        // range of num links to show
        $range = 3;
        ?>
        <div id="page">
        <?php
        // if not on page 1, don't show back links
        if ($currentpage > 1) 
        {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_GET['location'] ?>&currentpage=1" class="blue"><< first  </a>
            <?php
            // get previous page num
            $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_GET['location'] ?>&currentpage=<?php echo $prevpage ?>" class="blue">< previous  </a>
            <?php
        }
        // loop to show links to range of pages around current page
        for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++)
        {
           // if it's a valid page number...
           if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) 
           {
              // if we're on current page...
              if ($x == $currentpage)
              {
                 // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
                 echo " <b>$x</b> "; //needs to be RIGHT ALIGNED
              // if not current page...
              } 
              else 
              {
                 // make it a link
                 ?>
                 <a href="<?php echo $_GET['location'] ?>&currentpage=<?php echo $x ?>" class="blue"> <?php echo $x?></a>
                 <?php
              } // end else
           } // end if 
        } // end for                         
        // if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
        if ($currentpage != $totalpages && $totalpages!=0) 
        {
           // get next page
           $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;        
           ?>
           <a href="<?php echo $_GET['location'] ?>&currentpage=<?php echo $nextpage ?>" class="blue">  next ></a>
           <a href="<?php echo $_GET['location'] ?>&currentpage=<?php echo $totalpages ?>" class="blue">  last >></a>
           <?php
        } 
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
ComA::reportComment();
?>
```

Comment: This javascript being called by onClick is an ajax request and the php function reportComment is itself being called by ajax in another file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using XmlHttpRequest in wrong way. Better way is to use something like this - http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
Furthermore, you are calling deleteComment() on page load, not on button click

Comment: This is the function that is being called.....<?php   
include ("pass.php");

Class Delete
{
 static function deleteComment($comId)
 {
  $deleteComment=mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE id='" . $comId . "'") or die(mysql_error);
 }
}
Delete::deleteComment($_GET['id']);
?>

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with jQuery, it's pretty simple:

Change your delete button to something like this:

```
<a class="delete_btn" rel="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>" href="#"><img src="_" onmouseover="_" onmouseout="_"></a>
```

and put this little script somewhere beneath it:

```
<script>
  $('.delete_btn').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.get('deleteComment.php', {'id' : id}, function(data) {
      $('#div_with_the_deleted_comment').html('This comment was deleted.');
      return false;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I added the import statement <script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: nvm I fixed the problem with a much simpler solution. I used the link href to directly call the function and then redirect back to that page. Thanks for all your help though.